# How to pass array from one TableView to another in TabView Application in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Basically, I have a class called Signal. It inherits from NSObject. It has 2 properties :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property BOOL *favoriteStatus;
```

My application is a Tab View Application and it has 2 main sections, both containing TableViewControllers. Now what I want to do is display all the objects in the first TableViewController, but only those which are favourites in the second one. So instead of instantiating all the objects in implementations of both the TableViewControllers , is there any way I can pass that same array into the second view controller when the user switches tabs.

Also, is there any other way (NOT CORE DATA) that I can store which objects are favorites so that they can be loaded next time.

Thanks.

Comment: I know, that's one way to go. But is there any other ? Core Data is the most obvious one, no doubt. Still...

Comment: Use a data controller (custom class) which maintains the list of objects and mediates access. It could also do the filtering.

Comment: Care to explain why you don't want to use Core Data? Seems like a perfect tool to do what you're trying to achieve imo..

Comment: You are not following the MVC design pattern; you need to consider how to model the data and then give access to this model to all the views that care about it (via a controller).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a singleton (which you should only do if the object that is a singleton really represents a single entity), I would subclass the tabbarcontroller and create a property in that. This way, when the array changes, the tabbarcontroller can tell the childViewControllers by having the childViewController implement a protocol defined by the tabbar.

Answer (score 1):

More correct than singleton and easier than subclassing:

At any moment, you can get the reference of the siblings viewControllers through the `self.tabBarController.childViewControllers` property.

So, assuming you are in the first tab and want to pass data to the second tab controller, you can do this anywhere in the first tab controller:

```
MySecondController *secondController = [self.tabBarController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:1]; //second tab has index 1 (begins in 0).
secondController.someProperty = self.someProperty
```

And If you want to pass this data just when the second tab is selected, implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method `shouldSelectViewController:` and put the code inside it, like this:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   MySecondController *secondController = [self.tabBarController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:1]; //second tab has index 1 (begins in 0).
   if(viewController == secondController)
   {
      secondController.someProperty = self.someProperty 
   }
   return YES;
}
```

You can obviously do the samething inside the second controller, if you want to pass data back to the first.

Answer (score 0):

Create store class as a singleton, for example MyObjectsStore. Setup your objects in this class and implement method for retrieving them. It should look like the following:

```
[MyObjectStore sharedInstance].myObjects
```

Use it in first and second controllers.

Comment: Bit of a hack isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `prepareForSegue` method in the first ViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier"])
{
    NextViewController *nextViewController =
    segue.destinationViewController;
    nextViewController.delegate = self;
    nextViewController.yourArray = yourArray;
}
```